# How can I use JS attribute for links in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, attributes

trying to understand.
I have a js code,

```
 $(document).on('click','.plan_btn',function() {
        $('.ui-dropdown').removeClass('active');
        var tarifplanid=$(this).attr('data-tarifplanid');
        $('.planid').text(tarifplanid);
            $('.add_plan').addClass('show');
        });
```

I have a php code, with button, where I pass attr.

```
<button type="button" class="ui-component ui-button plan_btn" data-tarifplanid="<?php echo($plan->plan_id)?>">Select</button>
```

So, by pressing Select button, I will have an planID, which is 2 or 3 stored in .JS

Then, as test, I have the following code:

```
 <?php
    $test = <<<EOD
    <span class="planid"></span>
    EOD;
echo $test;?>
```

Question is:

1. echo returns ID, 2 or 3, depends on which item I pressed "Select"
2. But, when I trying to add a link with $test, it will as `<span class="planid"></span>`

Why? I assume it should be https://localhost/2 but I have `https://localhost/<span class="planid"></span>`

Thank you!
I'm not a developer, just browsing and a learning a bit

Comment: You mention that you tried to add a link with $test, can you show the code you tried?

Comment: @xrodas, simply using basic -                           echo "<a href='$test'>Link</a>";

Comment: echo return an INT, but variable itself, return <span class> :)